# SSL VPN Connection in Windows 10 is "aborted by the local system"

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, ssl

I'm trying to connect to the VPN of my company using Windows 10 built-in VPN client (SSL VPN) but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

The credentials are correct and the certificate chain is correct.

Is there a way to get more details on this error?

On my company's side, they see the following error in their logs:

```
Date Time: 2016-03-10 11:30:42
Date: 2016-03-10
Time: 11:30:42
Level: error error
Sub Type: sslvpn-session
ID: 39946
Virtual Domain: root
Action: ssl-exit-error
Tunnel ID: 0
Tunnel Type: ssl
Remote IP: [hidden]
Tunnel IP: N/A
User: N/A
Group: N/A
Dst Host: N/A
Reason: N/A
Message: SSL exit error
```

**I am able to connect to the VPN of my company using FortiClient.**

Comment: This sounds like a SSL certificate problem.  Verify the certificate is installed on the client machine.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, thanks for chiming in. We checked the certificate with https://www.digicert.com/help/ and it appears to be correctly installed.

Comment: Could it be something on my side, i.e. on my Windows machine?

Comment: That's checking if it's installed on the server, I asked, about the client machine

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread. How do I check that the certificate is properly installed on my machine?

Comment: You would need to add the certificate to the certificate store within Windows.

Comment: I followed these instructions: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows. As far as I can tell, I successfully added my company's certificate, but the problem persists, and the error message is the same. Any idea?

Comment: I have the exact same problem (and I can also connect with FortiClient). Have you ever figured out why it doesn't work?

Comment: @BrunoLM I haven't, unfortunately. I'm back to using the official FortiClient software...

Answer (score 2):

"The Windows VPN client only supports the protocols L2TP, PPTP, IKEv2 and Microsoft's SSTP.
OpenVPN is a SSL VPN"

https://serverfault.com/questions/826789/connect-to-vpn-in-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the SSTP VPN function in Windows 10 built-in VPN client, it is only for SSTP VPN, which is mostly provided by Windows server.

It is not comptible with Fortinet SSL VPN.